# JSON-LD: How can I have multiple articleSection?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

My blog post can have many categories. So how could I add those categories in `articleSection`?

With `itemprop` you could set it like this:

```
<span itemprop="articleSection">Sports</span> -
<span itemprop="articleSection">Politics</span> -
<span itemprop="articleSection">US News</span>
```

How do you do it with JSON-LD?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as an array:

```
"articleSection": [
    "Category 1",
    "Category 2"
]
```

Here's a full example within [BlogPosting](https://schema.org/BlogPosting) that will validate on the [Google Structured Data tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "BlogPosting",
  "name": "Apple announces iPhone SE",
  "headline": "Apple phone headline",
  "author": "John Smith",
  "image": "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
   "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Google",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://google.com/logo.jpg"
    }
  },
  "articleSection": [
    "Category 1",
    "Category 2"
  ],
  "datePublished": "2016-03-21T11:30:00-07:00",
  "description": "New iPhone announced at 11:30 in California."
}
</script>
```